# How to use ExtJS stripeRows with RowExpander plugin in IE8

Tags: css, extjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm using ExtJS 4.2.1 and have a grid using stripeRows, so the rows alternate grey and white. I am also using the RowExpander plugin. In Chrome and IE9+, everything looks great. In IE8 however, the expanded row background color is white for all rows. This makes the striping look terrible.

I've tried to add custom css to style the expanded cell background, but the grid is populated dynamically and I don't know how many rows are going to be in it, and IE8 does not support :nth-child css, so I was only able to set the background color for ALL expanded cells, not every other.

Has anyone figured out how to accomplish this? Thank you!

I am also not able to include jQuery into this application, so any jQuery solution to replace nth-child won't be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Since Ext generates each row of the grid as a table, the markup for each striped row in the grid looks like:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="x-grid-row-alt"> //normal striped row
    <tr class="x-grid-row-body-hidden"> //expanded row (collapsed)
</tbody>
```

You can use the adjacent-child css selector in IE8 to style the background color of the row descriptions of striped rows with:

```
.x-grid-row-alt + tr {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```